# Assigning User to a Profile through MetaData Api

Tags: metadata-api, profile, user, custom-profile

I am .net Developer, creating some POC on SFDC Metadata Api, so please bear with me if i ask silly question.

I am able to create a Profile and permission set in SFDC org, through metadata api. But am struggling to assign the profile to existing user.

Any suggestions.

Cheers !!

Comment: if u r not too specific about metadata api, you can use the standard enterprise api to update an user with the profile id you have.

Comment: The Metadata API supports modification of data that isn't in the normal SObject pattern. So AFAIK you will have to use a second API that does handle SObject data. I'd suggest the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) as its the simplest.